# !#/bin/bash: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell

First, I run

```
/bin/bash a.sh
```

It succeed.

But when I want to run

```
/bin/bash a.sh > a_info.txt
```

It failed.

```
Error: line 1: !#/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

It does not seem that it’s '`^M`' that’s causing this error.

Comment: You misspelled "#!/bin/bash".

Comment: I too, was going to vote to close as "too localized", but on second thought, this could be helpful to others who transpose the two characters (I know I've done it accidentally a number of times).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The shebang pattern is `#!/bin/your_shell`, not `!#/bin/your_shell`. Just fix the typo.

Comment: When you spend two hours trying to debug the script and it turns out that your shebang is wrong!

Answer (score 11):

**Check the file's encoding.**

If you get this error, but you did not misspell the 'shebang', have a close look at the file's encoding. I was getting this error on a file with encoding 'UTF8 with BOM'... I guess the BOM (Byte Order Mark) was causing the problem. Changed the encoding to ASCII and that fixed it (or you can use 'UTF-8 without BOM' which is effectively the same for files only containing ASCII characters).

Comment: That was the real problem in my case :)

Comment: You just save my life! Thanks!!

Comment: I think it is a bug in Bash actually. AFAIK, Unicode compliance means being able to cope with the BOM... I'm hoping Bash is (wanting to be) Unicode compliant? It would be a lot better if we could leave the BOM in imho, as it is actually an excellent mechanism to unambiguously encode the file encoding in the file itself, instead of having to rely on headers/metadata/manual config/guessing... But bugs like these are really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause of the "No such file or directory" error is if your shell script is using CRLF instead of LF line endings.